# Fastlane, screenshot custom action before simulator is launched?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I'm trying to launch quick time player to record video and audio from the iOS simulator.

I figure I can create a shell script with arrays for each of the the languages and each device. And loop around and run a fastlane lane, passing in there parameters.

I've seen that you can use `before_each` in your fastfile, but this will launch well before the simulator launches, however I need to launch quick time player just as the simulator launches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fastlane has no integrated support for QuickTime, so you'd need to do this yourself using shell scripts. Because the launch times for both QuickTime and Simulator are likely to vary, I think it will be difficult and error-prone to time this correctly.

If you want to continue exploring this approach, I would avoid using `before_each` and instead rely on a lane's ability to call another lane, e.g.:

```
lane :record_qt_video do
    my_languages = [] # some array of options
    # launch quicktime
    # launch simulator
    my_languages.each do |lang|
        launch_localized_app(language: lang)
        # save video and reset quicktime state
    end
end

private_lane :launch_localized_app do |options|
    lang = options[:language]
    # run whatever you want in the simulator
end
```

I see you're working on a [fastlane pull request](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/11744) that uses the integrated simulator recording option instead of QuickTime. I think this is likely to be a better approach because it will remove the timing issues from the equation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tried into the `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo` approach however it doesn't include audio in the video. Instead I'm quite far advanced to recording the audio with QuickTime and merging it into the video produced by SimCtl. However, I'm finding timing issues are still quite a big issue. As a starting point i'm using a PR which uses http listening to trigger the start / end of recording.

Comment: Unfortunately that PR has been declined already, however I must proceed as I have 45 videos to produce :( I'd be pleased to hear if you have any further comments.

Comment: I think you will need to take an approach that allows QuickTime to stay running, and then trim the video afterward. Since this is all done on the same computer with the same system clock, you could potentially use the time output from the test framework and the QuickTime files for the trimming. See the [QuickTime timecodes API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/QuickTime/RM/MovieBasics/MTEditing/I-Chapter/9TimecodeMediaHandle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000908-TimecodeMediaHandlerFunctions-SW1).

Comment: Also that PR isn't declined, it's just on hold until it's completed

Comment: This was the original PR https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/10121 which was closed / declined. In my PR I took out the listener code, the feature doesnt work without it. Thanks for your interest.